# Properties of the class of topological spaces possessing a CW-structure

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let ${\mathcal C}$ be the class of topological spaces which carry a CW-structure (note that I do not want to fix some particular CW-structure).

Is it true that for a covering map $E\stackrel{f}{\to} B$ with $E\in{\mathcal C}$ we have $B\in{\mathcal C}$, too?

It *is* true that the total space of a covering lies in ${\mathcal C}$ if the base space does, but the reverse implication is not clear to me.

**Edit**

As Algori pointed out, the quotient space is not even Hausdorff in general. What about finite regular coverings, i.e. those which come from a free action of a finite group on the total space? Is it true then that the quotient space carries a CW-structure, too?

I'm interested in that because this would imply that given a free group action of a finite group on a "nice" space like a CW-complex, one can always choose a CW-structure with respect to which $G$ just permutes cells. Then the corresponding cellular complex would be a (possibly nice) complex of ${\mathbb Z}G$-modules (for example, if the space was a sphere, then this procedures can be used to construct a periodic ${\mathbb Z}G$-resolution of the trivial module ${\mathbb Z}$, showing that the group has to have periodic invariants like homology and cohomology; in this particular case, however, things behave well as the quotient space ${\mathbb S}^n/G$ is still a compact manifold).

Thank you.

Comment: is there a counterexample where $B$ is hausdorff?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, here is a simple example when this fails: let $X$ be $\mathbf{R}^2$ minus the origin and consider the automorphism of $X$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,y/2)$. This automorphism generates a group $G$. The quotient map $X\to X/G$ is a covering, but $X/G$ is not Hausdorff.

This answers the question as it is stated, but maybe you wanted $B$ to be Hausdorff (in which case I don't know what to do).

Comment: This example can be found on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space.  (That's a good thing; I just wanted to point it out.)  It's interesting -- the fact that the quotient by a free, properly discontinuous group action can lose the Hausdorff property is something I had never thought of before.  Does this phenomenon show up naturally in algebraic or analytic geometry?

Comment: Pete -- thanks for the reference! Honestly, I can't see any direct analogies with algebraic geometry, only some fairly vague ones, when the quotient turns out to be worse than expected (e.g an algebraic space instead of a scheme etc). One of the problems is that I don't see how to translate "properly discontinuous" into algebraic/categorical language.

Comment: There are different uses for the phrase "properly discontinuous G-action" but if you take the definition that "for any compact subset K only finitely many images of K intersect itself", then the above counterexample disappears. Under this definition, if G acts freely and properly discontinuously on a manifold X, then the quotient X/G is a (Hausdorff) manifold and the projection is a covering map.   

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer it might help.

1. I tried searching on "$G$-CW-complexes" or "equivariant-CW-complexes", and  [this old paper](http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2261/6106/1/jfs180205.pdf) popped up. There it is mentioned that in the case of free actions of finite groups the notions of $G$-CW-complex and $G$-cell complex coincide (see Remark 1.12). In other words, if you have a cell complex $X$ on which a finite group $G$ acting freely by permuting cells, then $X$ is automatically a $G$-CW-complex.
2. On the other hand, I am skeptical that any free action of a finite group on a cell complex can be made cellular. For example, it is a hard theorem of Kirby-Siebenmann that any compact topological manifold has a CW-structure. If what you want is true, then this hard theorem would be easy for spherical space forms, because they are covered by spheres which are smoothable, hence have CW-structures.